# Simple Question About Expectation of a Product with Quotients

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification, expectation, independence

Let $X(k)$ be i.i.d. random variables with arbitrary density $f_X$ and mean $\mathbb{E}[X(k)] =\mu$ for $k=0,1,...,N-1$. Let $a \in \mathbb{R}^1$, I would like to compute
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[ {\prod\limits_{k = 0}^{N - 1} {\frac{{1 - aX\left( k \right)}}{{1 + aX\left( k \right)}}} } \right].
$$
Below is my thinking:
\begin{align*}
  \mathbb{E}\left[ {\prod\limits_{k = 0}^{N - 1} {\frac{{1 - aX\left( k \right)}}{{1 + aX\left( k \right)}}} } \right] 
&= \prod\limits_{k = 0}^{N - 1} {\mathbb{E}\left[ {\frac{{1 - aX\left( k \right)}}{{1 + aX\left( k \right)}}} \right]}  \hfill \\
   &?= \prod\limits_{k = 0}^{N - 1} {\frac{{\mathbb{E}\left[ {1 - aX\left( k \right)} \right]}}{{\mathbb{E}\left[ {1 + aX\left( k \right)} \right]}}}  \hfill \\
   &= \prod\limits_{k = 0}^{N - 1} {\frac{{1 - a\mathbb{E}\left[ {X\left( k \right)} \right]}}{{1 + a\mathbb{E}\left[ {X\left( k \right)} \right]}}}  \hfill \\
   &= {\left( {\frac{{1 - a\mu }}{{1 + a\mu }}} \right)^N} \hfill \\ 
\end{align*} 
But I am somewhat bothers with my second equality above since I am not clear if it is allowed to take expectation on the denominator and numerator separately under i.i.d. condition. (I was thinking perhaps using iterated conditional expectation + i.i.d. might help me out). Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're right that that step isn't allowed in general -- I can't think of an explicit counterexample at the moment though.

Comment: Two reasons why $$E\left(\frac{1-aX}{1+aX}\right)\ne\frac{E(1-aX)}{E(1+aX)}$$ First, $1-aX$ and $1+aX$ are not independent, second $$E\left(\frac{1}{1+aX}\right)\ne\frac{1}{E(1+aX)}$$ All you can do here is to write  $$\mathbb{E}\left[ {\prod\limits_{k = 0}^{N - 1} {\frac{{1 - aX\left( k \right)}}{{1 + aX\left( k \right)}}} } \right] =g(a)^N\qquad g(a)=\mathbb{E}\left[ {\frac{{1 - aX\left( 0 \right)}}{{1 + aX\left( 0 \right)}}} \right]$$ and to compute $$g(a)=\int\frac{1-ax}{1+ax}f_X(x)dx$$

Comment: @William This is odd that you cannot, **any** (not almost surely constant) random variable works to disprove the OP's assertion.